# How to sequentially execute functions in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

want to execute 3 functions sequentially using angularjs.

function doThis(callback) {

```
                 $scope.db.transaction(function (transaction) {

                     transaction.executeSql("insert into tbl1(---) values (?,?,?)", []);

                 });              

             if (typeof callback === 'function') {

                 callback();
             }
         }

         function doThat() {

             $scope.db.transaction(function (transaction) {
                 transaction.executeSql("select * from tbl1 orderby col1 desc limit 1", [], function (transaction, result) {

                    //some code

                 });
             });
         }

         doThis(doThat);
```

want to execute doThis first than after finishing doThis, doThat will execute.

Comment: Please reformat your question!

Comment: how to format it..i'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Please provide more information : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the promise service of AngularJS, called [**$q**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

A simple way to use it can be the above code, but take a look to the link I shared before.

```
firstFunction.then(function() {
    // Will be call after firstFunction
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       function doThis(callback) {

             var executeOnSuccess = false;
             $scope.db.transaction(function (transaction) {

                 transaction.executeSql("insert into tbl1(---) values (?,?,?)", []);
          executeOnSuccess = true;
             });              

         if (typeof callback === 'function' && executeOnSuccess ) {

             callback();
         }
     }

     function doThat() {

         $scope.db.transaction(function (transaction) {
             transaction.executeSql("select * from tbl1 orderby col1 desc limit 1", [], function (transaction, result) {

                //some code

             });
         });
     }

     doThis(doThat);
```